# Copied module folder not linked with android studio main project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, module

I am developing an application which is currently built in android studio. Now i want to import an Eclipse project as a module in my android studio project. I successfully added that module in android studio but when i try to launch a new Intent/Activity from a java class which is in main project and try to open an activity which is in my module folder then the import is not successfully done.

```
startActivity(new Intent(ActivityNotification.this, UnityPlayer.class));
```

Now UnityPlayer class is the java file which is in my module project and i want to open it but no import is found i.e there is an error on UnityPlayer saying that cannot resolve this. I think the module is not successfully linked or it has some other issue Please Help what to do here

Comment: have you added the module as a dependency / library to your main project? Is it included in your top level `settings.gradle` file

Comment: yes following line is written in it
include ':AlarmGame', ':library', ':clonyBird'

where clonyBird is my module name

Comment: I'm guessing **AlarmGame** is your main project. Have you added clonyBird as a dependency to it? If not, you should add to the dependencies in AlarmGame's `build.gradle` file. i.e add  `compile project(':clonyBird')`

Comment: Yes that works Thankyou sir :)